# Better arrow cone rotation using ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm drawing an arrow between pick and place points using `QuadraticBezierCurve3` and `ConeGeometry`, but the rotation of the cone is not perfect as you can see in the snippet down!

Can you please tell me how can I improve the visualization (cone rotation) of my arrow function? thanks in advance.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

 /**
 draw arrow
*/
function drawArrow(pick_pos, place_pos, scene) {
    /**
    * Curve
    */
    const start = new THREE.Vector3();
    start.add(pick_pos)
    
    const finish = new THREE.Vector3();
    finish.add(place_pos)

    let mid = new THREE.Vector3();
    mid.add(start);
    let dist = finish.x + mid.x;
    mid.x = dist/2;
    mid.y += 3;

const b_curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(
    start,
    mid,
    finish
);
const points = b_curve.getPoints( 100 );
const line_geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0ffffb, linewidth:5 } );
const curve = new THREE.Line( line_geometry, material );
/**
 * Cone
 */
const cone_geometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry( 0.2, 1, 8 );
const cone_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff00fb });

const cone = new THREE.Mesh( cone_geometry, cone_material );
cone.position.set(points[98].x, points[98].y, points[98].z);
cone.rotateX(Math.PI * points[100].x); 
cone.rotateZ(Math.PI * points[100].z);

/**
 * Arrow
 */

const arrow = new THREE.Group();
arrow.add(curve);
arrow.add(cone);
arrow.name = 'arrow';
scene.add(arrow);
}

/**
 Create the scene, camera, renderer
*/
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x21252d);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 8;
  camera.position.z = 10;
  scene.add(camera);
  
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  const pick = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  const place = new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 5);
  drawArrow(pick, place, scene);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. The cone's default position points the sky(z); it invalidates the rotation.
2. It seems the arc's direction is inverted.
3. `.lookAt()` is a great shortcut for getting rotation from two different 3D vectors.

```js
// ANSWER
const VEnd = points[15].clone();
// fix cone's default position which points skyward.
cone.geometry.rotateX( -Math.PI / 2 );
cone.lookAt(VEnd);
```

try run the code below:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

 /**
 draw arrow
*/
function drawArrow(pick_pos, place_pos, scene) {
    /**
    * Curve
    */
    const start = new THREE.Vector3();
    start.add(pick_pos)
    
    const finish = new THREE.Vector3();
    finish.add(place_pos)

    let mid = new THREE.Vector3();
    mid.add(start);
    let dist = finish.x + mid.x;
    mid.x = dist/2;
    mid.y += 3;

const b_curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(
    start,
    mid,
    finish
);
const points = b_curve.getPoints( 100 );
const line_geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0ffffb, linewidth:5 } );
const curve = new THREE.Line( line_geometry, material );
/**
 * Cone
 */
const cone_geometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry( 0.2, 1, 8 );
const cone_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff00fb });

const cone = new THREE.Mesh( cone_geometry, cone_material );
// ANSWER
const VEnd = points[15].clone();
// fix cone's default position which points skyward.
cone.geometry.rotateX( -Math.PI / 2 );
cone.lookAt(VEnd);

/**
 * Arrow
 */

const arrow = new THREE.Group();
arrow.add(curve);
arrow.add(cone);
arrow.name = 'arrow';
scene.add(arrow);
}

/**
 Create the scene, camera, renderer
*/
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x21252d);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 8;
  camera.position.z = 10;
  scene.add(camera);
  
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  const pick = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  const place = new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 5);
  drawArrow(pick, place, scene);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```